# How to change window color of mathematica?

Tags: user-interface

My mathematica interface changed color and became blueish. It is very hard to read it. What is the option to revert to the original color?

I am on (Arch) Linux.

[image]

Comment: Is looks like OS setting, aren't other windows affected?

Comment: That is the weird thing. Only mathematica is affected. I tried to do clean reinstall of gtk related packages to no avail.

Comment: My go to answer for 'weird things' happening: [try a cleanstart](http://support.wolfram.com/kb/12464).